# Do weapon stats include bonuses from skills, class mods, etc?

Tags: borderlands-2

It seems that weapon bonuses that are on the weapon itself are accounted for in the weapon's stats, but are bonuses for skills, class mods, badass bonuses, etc?  If not, is there any way I *can* see what my actual stats are?

Comment: I was meaning to test this. I wonder if badass bonuses are counted too

Comment: Easy to test.  Go to the beginning area and shoot a bullywog.  See the damage from a body shot.  Go reset your skill points.  Check the numbers on the gun, then shoot the bullywog again.  See the numbers that pop up.  Do the same by turning off Badass perks and by removing class mods.  Haven't tried this myself, obviously.

Comment: You can just turn off your badass perks and see if the values for your weapons change...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weapon stats shown are always the base stats, not including skills, mods or badass bonuses.

To test this I checked out an SMG. With no bonuses, no skills or class mod, it has 54 damage. With a class mod increasing SMG damage 71%, a skill increasing bullet damage 20% and about 3% damage boost from Badass stat bonuses. The gun still showed 54 damage.

Note gun damage also doesn't indicate your level's effect on damage, so guns generally do vastly more real damage than their stats indicate; stats are mostly there to compare guns.