# Are weapon modifiers in Borderlands 2 applied before or after the displayed stats?

Tags: borderlands-2

I wondered about this all the way through Borderlands and now I'm seeing the same thing in Borderlands 2. If a weapon has, for instance, 200 damage, and a modifier that says "+20% weapon damage", does that mean that the weapon actually has 240 damage or that the weapon had 166 damage before the mod was applied?

---

The answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85756/when-do-my-skill-point-modifiers-apply) sort of answers the question for Borderlands, but I'm still not sure in Borderlands 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do weapon stats include bonuses from skills, class mods, etc?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85187/do-weapon-stats-include-bonuses-from-skills-class-mods-etc)

Comment: @BenBrocka Not a duplicate. This is about bonuses from the weapon parts themselves, not skills or anything external.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Skill bonuses, badass bonuses, and bonuses from other equipment are applied after the item card. Whatever modifiers are listed on the item card are applied **before** item card totals.

Everything you see on the weapon card is final (for the weapon). If the card says 200 damage, the gun will do 200 damage on a body shot in the hands of an unskilled, dull, non-badass character. In your example, the gun *did 166 damange before a modifier*.

More often bonuses listed on the item card have no corresponting totals displayed, so they are important - like critical damage or stability.